# Key binding for separating storm not working

Tags: pc, mass-effect-2

I want to change my default keybindings for Mass Effect 2 through Coalesced.ini so that the following happens:

1. Storm is separated from Use/Cover
2. Storm is bound to `LeftShift`
3. Use/Cover is bound to `E`
4. Command HUD is bound to `Spacebar`

I moved Order Move/Attack Henchmen 2 from `E` to `T` so `E` would become available for 3.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/p6zNkG2m) is my Coalesced.ini so far. Everything is working the way I want it to be, except LeftShift doesn't trigger Storm. There doesn't seem to be an extra LeftShift defined KeyBinding, so I'm lost. What is wrong?

Edit: Line 66 and 92 are the most important ones to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after asking for help to another source.

`OnHold` on line 66 doesn't accept `0.0` as a parameter. Either change it to the default `0.2` or remove `OnHold 0.0` all together to make it instant.